# Cant validate form data or insert into database (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am working with Codeigniter framework these days. I am trying to validate my form data using codeigniter's form_validation library. The problem is I cant get it to work. I dont know where the problem is no error is being shown.

**Here is the view page** I am calling controller **core** and function **postad** in **form action**

```
<div class="container table-responsive" id="con1">



    <div class="row" id="h4_subad">
        <div class="col-md-4"><h4>Submit an Ad</h4></div>
    </div>

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="get" action="/core/postad">
   <table id="form_table" class="table-responsive table table-striped" id="table_form">

       <td>Ad Title*</td><td><input class="form-control" name="ad_title" id="ad_title" type="text" placeholder="Enter Title" id="ad_form"></td>

       <tr>  <td>Select Category*</td> <td><select name="ad_form" class="form-control" id="ad_form">
  <option>Electronics</option>
  <option>Mobiles & Accessories</option>
  <option>Computers & Accessories</option>
  <option>Kitchen Applicances</option>
  <option>Clothing</option>
               </select></td></tr>

       <tr><td>Ad Description*</td><td><textarea name="txt_area" id="txt_area" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Description" ></textarea></td></tr>

       <tr><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="core/postad">Submit Ad</button></td></tr>
   </table>

</form>  
</div>
```

**Controller for this view**

```
class Core extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {


        $this->load->view('header1');
        $this->load->view('body');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }

    public function product() {


        $this->load->view('header1');
        $this->load->view('product');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }

    public function contact() {


        $this->load->view('header1');
        $this->load->view('contact');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }

    public function aboutus() {

        $this->load->view('header1');
        $this->load->view('aboutus');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
      public function reg() {

        $this->load->view('header1');
        $this->load->view('reg');
        $this->load->view('footer');
        $this->input->get('username');

      }

       public function postad() {

        $this->load->view('header1');
        $this->load->view('postad');
        $this->load->view('footer');

        $this->load->model('insert_model');
   $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');

//Validating Name Field
$this->form_validation->set_rules('txt_area', 'Text Area', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[15]');



if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
$this->load->view('postad');
}

else {
//Setting values for tabel columns
$data = array(
'description' => $this->input->post('txt_area'),
);
//Transfering data to Model
$this->insert_model->form_insert($data);
$data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';
//Loading View
$this->load->view('insert_view', $data);
}
}
}
```

**Model for database connectivity**

```
<?php
class insert_model extends CI_Model{
function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
}
function form_insert($data){

$this->db->insert('post_ad', $data);
}
}
?>
```

Only trying it for just one field **txt_area**

I dont want to use codeigniter's form helper as I am using bootstrap form.

Comment: You're not posting anything, your form in your HTML is set to GET method, change it to POST method.

Comment: Could you confirm that ur core controller in being run at all? try to echo something and put an exit; after that.

Comment: i think there is something wrong with button itself, i am trying to load another view using form action=/core/contactus but its not working. core controller does work for when i click a link e.g there is a link on my main page MeetUS, this calls aboutus() function in the controller.

Comment: try loading the `form_validation` library before calling the views. Also in the button add a '/'  i.e. write `onclick="/core/postad"`

Comment: @Ben the form_validation does not needs to be loaded before the view. It needs to be loaded before use. Along with I would not use onclick anymore because it isn't going to be supported much longer.

Comment: @AliRehman Make your button type submit

Comment: changed type to submit. now data is being inserted into my db on its will. sometimes it puts 0 value in db. Still not verifying. also because of `if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
$this->load->view('postad');
}` double post ad view is being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `validation_errors();` in posted.php file (**HTML**) for display error message which you validate.

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

**[Form Validation User Manual](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html)**

Answer (score 0):

You should echo the `validation_errors();`   as below in your html . For more information you can vist [this](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html)

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

    <div class="row" id="h4_subad">
        <div class="col-md-4"><h4>Submit an Ad</h4></div>
    </div>

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="get" action="/core/postad">
   <table id="form_table" class="table-responsive table table-striped" id="table_form">

       <td>Ad Title*</td><td><input class="form-control" name="ad_title" id="ad_title" type="text" placeholder="Enter Title" id="ad_form"></td>

       <tr>  <td>Select Category*</td> <td><select name="ad_form" class="form-control" id="ad_form">
  <option>Electronics</option>
  <option>Mobiles & Accessories</option>
  <option>Computers & Accessories</option>
  <option>Kitchen Applicances</option>
  <option>Clothing</option>
               </select></td></tr>

       <tr><td>Ad Description*</td><td><textarea name="txt_area" id="txt_area" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Description" ></textarea></td></tr>

       <tr><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="core/postad">Submit Ad</button></td></tr>
   </table>

</form>  
</div>
```

Comment: didnt work. also validation is not the only problem here. even if i ignore validating the data, its not inserted in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Your button to submit the form is incorrect. When you try to submit a form make sure to set the type to submit too.

```
<button type="submit">Submit form</button>
```

or

```
<submit>Submit form</submit>
```